# Are csvsimple and tabularray incompatible?

Tags: csvsimple, tabularray

Is there an incompatibility between `csvsimple` and the new package `tabularray`? The following MWE throws an error. (Compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman,french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{tabularray} %needs package ninecolors.sty
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
frA,frB,deA
un cogne,arg.,ein Bulle
morfler,arg.,eins abkriegen
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

This is what I'd like to obtain, with environment \verb|tblr|:

\noindent
\begin{tblr}{colspec={X[2,l]X[4,l]},
width=0.5\linewidth,
hlines,
}
\textit{un cogne} (arg.)& \textit{un policier ou un gendarme}\\ 
\textit{morfler} (arg.)& {\selectlanguage{ngerman}\textit{eins abkriegen}}\\
\end{tblr}

\bigskip

A normal tabular seems to work (but I'd miss the fonctions of tabularray...)
(not only the X column type, also the alignment facilities):

% \csvreader

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{8cm}}\toprule
\csvreader[
  late after line=\\\midrule,
  late after last line=\\\bottomrule,
  head to column names,
  ]{data.csv}{}{%
  \textit{\frA} (\frB) & \textit{\deA}
}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

But this throws an error:

\noindent
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={X[2,l]X[4,l]},
  width=0.5\linewidth,
  hlines,
}
\csvreader[
  late after line=\\\midrule,
  late after last line=\\\bottomrule,
  head to column names,
  ]{data.csv}{}{%
  \textit{\frA} (\frB) & \textit{\deA}
}
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not surprised at all, tabularray creates tabulars in a quite different way, if you want cvsimple to support it, you should make a feature request.

Comment: A known limitation of `tabularray`, see https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/23.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

With `csvsimple` v2.1.0 (2021/07/06), `csvsimple-l3` gets compatible with `tabularray`.

You should use `\usepackage[l3]{csvsimple}` or `\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}` to load `csvsimple-l3`, rather than the superseded `csvsimple-legacy`.

```tex
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
frA,frB,deA
un cogne,arg.,ein Bulle
morfler,arg.,eins abkriegen
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman,french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{tabularray} %needs package ninecolors.sty
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[l3]{csvsimple} % or "\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}"

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Desired output}
This is what I'd like to obtain, with environment \verb|tblr|:

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={X[2,l]X[4,l]},
  width=0.5\linewidth,
  hlines,
}
  \textit{un cogne} (arg.) & \textit{un policier ou un gendarme}\\ 
  \textit{morfler} (arg.)  & {\selectlanguage{ngerman}\textit{eins abkriegen}}\\
\end{tblr}


\subsection*{With \texttt{tabular} env}
A normal tabular seems to work (but I'd miss the functions of tabularray...)
(not only the X column type, also the alignment facilities):

\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{8cm}}\toprule
\csvreader[
  late after line=\\\midrule,
  late after last line=\\\bottomrule,
  head to column names,
  ]{data.csv}{}{%
  \textit{\frA} (\frB) & \textit{\deA}
}
\end{tabular}


\subsection*{With \texttt{tblr} env}

% required by tabularray
\NewTableCommand\toprule{\hline[0.08em]}
\NewTableCommand\midrule{\hline[0.05em]}
\NewTableCommand\bottomrule{\hline[0.08em]}

\csvreader[
  tabularray={
      colspec={X[2,l]X[4,l]},
      width=0.5\linewidth,
%      hlines
  },
  table head=\toprule,
  late after line=\\\midrule,
  late after last line=\\\bottomrule,
  head to column names,
]{data.csv}{}{%
  \noexpand\textit{\frA} (\frB) & \noexpand\textit{\deA}
}

\end{document}
```

Output is the same as below.

**Original:**

Here is a first try on the `csvsimple` side. The idea is to make `\csvloop` (in the taste of `csvsimple-legacy`) firstly store the whole tabular staff in a macro (here `\csv@output`), instead of directly printing them. Then user can use `\csvoutput` to print the table.

Restricted by how `tabularray` is implemented, every `\hline`-like staff, `\\`, and `&` should be directly seen in `\csv@output`.

```tex
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
frA,frB,deA
un cogne,arg.,ein Bulle
morfler,arg.,eins abkriegen
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman,french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{tabularray} %needs package ninecolors.sty
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

%%%
%%% patch for csvsimple-lagency
%%%
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifcsv@storeonly

\csvset{
  % new keys
  table env/.store in=\csv@tableenv,
  store only/.is if=csv@storeonly,
  % redefinition
  tabular/.style={
    @table={\csv@pretable\begin{\csv@tableenv}{#1}\csv@tablehead}{\csv@tablefoot\end{\csv@tableenv}\csv@posttable},
    late after line=\\
  },
  % init new keys
  table env=tabular,
  store only=false
}

% store-or-print patch for \csvloop
\long\def\csvloop#1{%
  % reset
  \global\let\csv@output\@empty
  \global\let\@endloophook\csv@empty%
  \global\let\csvlinetotablerow\csv@assemble@csvlinetotablerow%
  % options
  \csvset{default,every csv,#1}%
  \csv@preprocss%
  \csv@set@catcodes%
  \csv@print@or@ostore\csv@prereading%
  \csv@print@or@ostore\csv@table@begin%
  \setcounter{csvinputline}{0}%
  % start reading
  \openin\csv@file=\csv@input@filename\relax%
  \ifeof\csv@file%
    \csv@error{File '\csv@input@filename' not existent, not readable, or empty!}{}%
  \else%
    % the head line
    \csv@opt@processheadline%
  \fi%
  %
  \setcounter{csvrow}{0}%
  \gdef\csv@do@preline{%
    \csv@print@or@ostore\csv@prefirstline%
    \gdef\csv@do@preline{\csv@print@or@ostore\csv@preline}%
  }%
  \gdef\csv@do@postline{%
    \csv@print@or@ostore\csv@postfirstline%
    \gdef\csv@do@postline{\csv@print@or@ostore\csv@postline}%
  }%
  \gdef\csv@do@@latepostline{%
    \csv@print@or@ostore\csv@latepostfirstline%
    \gdef\csv@do@latepostline{\csv@print@or@ostore\csv@latepostline}%
  }%
  \gdef\csv@do@latepostline{%
    \csv@print@or@ostore\csv@lateposthead%
    \global\let\csv@do@latepostline=\csv@do@@latepostline%
  }%
  % command for the reading loop
  \gdef\csv@iterate{%
    \let\csv@usage=\csv@empty%
    \csvreadnext%
    \ifeof\csv@file%
      \global\let\csv@next=\csv@empty%
    \else%
      \global\let\csv@next=\csv@iterate%
      \ifx\csv@par\csvline\relax%
        \else%
        \csv@escanline{\csvline}%
        % check and decide
        \csv@opt@checkcolumncount%
      \fi%
    \fi%
    % do or do not
    \csv@usage%
    \csv@next}%
  \ifeof\csv@file%
    \global\let\csv@next=\csv@empty%
  \else%
    \global\let\csv@next=\csv@iterate%
  \fi%
  \csv@next%
  \closein\csv@file%
  \@endloophook%
  \csv@print@or@ostore\csv@latepostlastline%
  \csv@print@or@ostore\csv@table@end%
  \csv@print@or@ostore\csv@postreading%
  \csv@reset@catcodes%
}

\newcommand\csvoutput{%
  % expose tabular-like env name
  \xpatchcmd@self\csv@output\csv@tableenv
  \xpatchcmd@self\csv@output\csv@tableenv
  % expose hrule-like commands
  \xpatchcmd@self\csv@output\csv@tablehead
  \xpatchcmd@self\csv@output\csv@tablefoot
  % output
  \csv@output
}

% helper, \xpatchcmd#1{#2}{<one-step expansion of #2>}{}{\fail}
\newcommand\xpatchcmd@self[2]{%
  \expanded{\unexpanded{\xpatchcmd#1{#2}}{\unexpanded\expandafter{#2}}}{}{\fail}%
}

% store-or-print patch for \csv@do@linecommand
\xpatchcmd\csv@do@linecommand
  {\csv@body}
  {\csv@print@or@estore\csv@body}
  {}{\fail}


% expand once
\def\csv@print@or@ostore#1{\csv@print@or@store@meta
  {\expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\csv@output\expandafter{#1}}
  {#1}}

% fully expansion
\def\csv@print@or@estore#1{\csv@print@or@store@meta
  {\expanded{\noexpand\g@addto@macro\noexpand\csv@output{#1}}}
  {#1}}

\def\csv@print@or@store@meta{%
  \ifcsv@storeonly
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother
%%%
%%% end of patch
%%%

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Desired output}
This is what I'd like to obtain, with environment \verb|tblr|:

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={X[2,l]X[4,l]},
  width=0.5\linewidth,
  hlines,
}
  \textit{un cogne} (arg.) & \textit{un policier ou un gendarme}\\ 
  \textit{morfler} (arg.)  & {\selectlanguage{ngerman}\textit{eins abkriegen}}\\
\end{tblr}


\subsection*{With \texttt{tabular} env}
A normal tabular seems to work (but I'd miss the functions of tabularray...)
(not only the X column type, also the alignment facilities):

\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{8cm}}\toprule
\csvreader[
  late after line=\\\midrule,
  late after last line=\\\bottomrule,
  head to column names,
  ]{data.csv}{}{%
  \textit{\frA} (\frB) & \textit{\deA}
}
\end{tabular}


\subsection*{With \texttt{tblr} env}
\csvreader[
  table env=tblr,
  tabular={
      colspec={X[2,l]X[4,l]},
      width=0.5\linewidth,
%      hlines
  },
  store only,
  table head=\toprule,
  late after line=\\\midrule,
  late after last line=\\\bottomrule,
  head to column names,
]{data.csv}{}{%
  \noexpand\textit{\frA} (\frB) & \noexpand\textit{\deA}
}

\NewTableCommand\toprule{\hline[0.08em]}
\NewTableCommand\midrule{\hline[0.05em]}
\NewTableCommand\bottomrule{\hline[0.08em]}

\csvoutput

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm impressed, and happy that I don't have to understand this all :) Who should get the feature request, the author of `tabularray` or the author of `csvsimple`?

Comment: I sent a feature request to the authors.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that a feature request has been opened in https://github.com/T-F-S/csvsimple/issues/13 .

Comment: @benjamin Hi, `csvsimple` has updated to add support for `tabularray`, and my answer is updated as well.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ `2021/07/01` should be `2021/07/06`.

Comment: @L.J.R. fixed, thanks